# Retrofit headers interceptor does not change header

Tags: android, header, retrofit2

I have android app with few api calls. I noticed that every call has 
`@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")` annotation in ApiService so I decided remove annotation and add header via interceptor to all requests:

```
    val headers = { chain: Interceptor.Chain ->
        val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build()
        chain.proceed(request)
    }

    val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(headers)
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .build()

    val customGson = GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(NameValuesList::class.java, NamesValuesListConverter())
            .create()

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://www.$fullDomain")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(customGson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build()

    service = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
```

But after that server return error on api call.
In logs I see that when I have explicit `@Headers()` annotation:

```
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json
```

And after replace it with interceptor:

```
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

I tried to change interceptor to this one:

```
    val headers = { chain: Interceptor.Chain ->
        val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                .headers(Headers.of(mutableMapOf("Content-Type" to "test")))
                .build()
        chain.proceed(request)
    }
```

But I still see this in log:

```
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

So looks like my interceptor does not apply or overridden. How to fix it?

**UPD**. I found the reason: when I add GsonConverterFactory it automatically add header `Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8`. Are there any way to avoid it without implementing custom ConverterFactory?

Answer (score 1):

as documentation says :
"Note: Headers do not overwrite each other. All headers with the same name will be included in the request."

refer to [retrofit Headers](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Header.html)

Comment: Yesm it looks true, when I added header "test: test" ir appears in logs. But how avoid adding `Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8` header by default?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if header exist.

```
val headers = { chain: Interceptor.Chain ->
    val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
    if(chain.request().header("Content-Type") == null){
        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    }
    chain.proceed(request.build())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Try this*

`chain.request().newBuilder().removeHeader("Content-Type") .headers(Headers.of(mutableMapOf("Content-Type" to "test"))) .build()`